# Create a Mongoose schema that is not required, of type string, with enum and default null?

Tags: typescript, mongoose, schema

Is it possible to set up a mongoose schema that fulfils the following requirements:

1. is **NOT** required
2. is of type "string" `type: String`
3. has an enum `enum: ['red', 'green']`
4. has a default set to **null** `default: null`

Comment: What have you tried? What result did you get?

Comment: I've provided an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

So, I managed to figure it out. It became clear when I read a bit more and understood what happens when you define different things.

---

**Goal**: I want to have a mongoose schema property that's either `null` or `string`. If it's a `string`, I want to validate and check if the value is strictly equal to one of the values in the given array.

---

```
color: {
  type: String,
  enum: ['red', 'green'],
  default: null
}
```

This **won't work**. There are two scenarios:

1. If the `color` property *exists* on the incoming object, then its
   value gets validated by the `enum` validator and all is good.
2. If the `color` property *does not exist* on the incoming object, I
   want to save `null` as a value for `color`. In this case, the
   incoming property `color` is `undefined`, so whatever we've defined
   for the `default` is taken as the value to be set for `color` and
   like in the first scenario, it will be validated by the `enum`
   validator. Obviously, having `null` will result in an error. To
   avoid that, I replaced the `enum` validator with a custom validator.

---

```
color: {
  type: String,
  validate: (value: string | null) => {
    if (value === null) return true;
    
    return ['red', 'green'].includes(value); // you could use enum here
    // return Object.values(MyEnum).includes(value as MyEnum);
  },
  default: null
}
```

Our custom validator will *always* run, because according to [Mongoose's docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#custom-validators), validators are not run on undefined values, which we won't have in any case.

**Note:** The only exception to Mongoose's rule is the `required` validator, which will guarantee that `color` *won't be* `undefined` when other validators run. But that is not my case. I want `color` to be optional. My reason is I don't want the front-end to make sure and send it if it's not required by business logic.

Answer (score 0):

use mongoose middleware

**ex:**

```js
const colorSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        color: String
    }
)

//                      middleware
colorSchema.pre("save", function (next) {

    if (this.color == 'red' || this.color == 'green' || this.color == "blue") null
    else {this.color = null}
    next()
})


const ColorModel = mongoose.model('colour', colorSchema)
```